# How to analyse change in time in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have following data in Excel:

Name, Status, Date

- Name is name of Book and combination Name, Date is unique.
- Status is one of 4 possible statuses

  - In stock
  - Ordered
  - Rented
  - Missing
- Date is date of entry

Data are entered every week and they like this:

```
Name, Status, Date
ABCD, In Stock, 1/1/2017
BCDE, Ordered, 1/1/2017
CDEF, Rented, 1/1/2017
DEFG, Rented, 1/1/2017
ABCD, In Stock, 10/1/2017
BCDE, In Stock, 10/1/2017
CDEF, In Stock, 10/1/2017
ABCD, IN Stock, 20/1/2017
BCDE, Rented, 20/1/2017
CDEF, Rented, 20/1/2017
EFGH, Ordered, 20/1/2017
```

What I need to find are few thinks:

1. how many entries were added each date and how many removed?
2. which books have same status for all Dates (or selected dates using slicer)
3. Is it possible to do such things using pivots? Or do I need different tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can put pivot tables:
1. For book status by date Columns: Status, Rows: Date, Values: Count of Name

2. For Unique Status all dates: Columns: Name, Rows: Date, Values Count of Status.
   Then you can just look at the sum for each column - which ever has 1 - thats the book you are looking for.

Hope it helps.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not really, first pivot tells how many entries with particular type were there for given date, but not the change. Change is entry removed for 10/1/2017 and one entry added for 20/1/2017. This can be deduced from sample data set, but if the data set will be longer and will be both removals and new entries this will not be visible (for example one entry removed and two added will actually produce just 5 as grand total - that would look like +1 but in fact is different)

Comment: Second pivot only says that item have status in given date, but I want to know if the status is same for all the time. (I want to identify items that don't change)

Comment: Well i guess if the grand total of the second table for any book is 1 - it means its status hasn't changed at all.